# How do I get the value of the last record in a dataset column? - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a dataset column which is "newsID".
I want to get the value of it's last record so that I can use it as a default value or starting point to auto increment when I add a new record using the BindingNavigator.

Thank you for your help!!!:)

Comment: Is there any reason that you are having to do the auto increment manually? Are you running against a text file or something rather than an RDBMS?

Answer (score 4):

If newsID is an integer you could do this with the Compute method:

```
Dim iLastNewsID As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Compute("Max(newsID)", Nothing)
```

Or if the order is reliable already and you simply want the last row in the DataSet then I don't see a problem with this:

```
Dim iLastNewsID As Integer = ds.Tables(0)(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("newsID")
```